# SSIS error in Data Flow Task with Dynamic connection

Tags: sql, ssis

I have very basic skills in developing SSIS packages; and getting errors while developing this new package. With this package, the SQLInstance is getting determined fine as can be seen in column mapping in the second picture. But it is not reading columns from the columns of a user table (IndexType column, in this case). This is the issue.

Tried below steps with no luck till now:

1. I set the VaidateExternalMetaData setting to False, still same error.
2. Already removed all columns one-by-one to identify whether it is issue with some specific data type, still same issue.
3. Created a brand new test package, same error in test package also.
4. Another package working fine in production with same settings with a user database. Copied the DataFlowTask component from it and used it new package, still same issue.

Please help. Many thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can not use temporal tables whilst declaring result set in OLEDB source, why cant u use direct result set from the query

Comment: Looks like that commandlog table doesnt exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be SQL server version.  I had similar issue when using table variables or temp tables.  You need to use with result set, similar to this:

```
EXEC('SELECT 43112609 AS val;')
WITH RESULT SETS
(
  (
    val VARCHAR(10)
  )
);
```

Article here:
http://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server-2012-t-sql-glance-execute-result-sets

SQL can not tell what is being returned when using temp/table variablbes so you have to specify this.  It is needed for some versions of SQL Server.